# Passing a PHP value to a page and back

Tags: php

Although sending the form to the receiving page works normally (via $_POST), I'd like to know how it can be sent back through an `<a>` tag. Is it possible without the use of AJAX or any JS scripts? I'm thinking about using cookies but have no idea on how to set it in-between the PHP/HTML scripts.

Here's a code sample for what I'm doing

Question page:

```
<form action="results.php" method="POST">
  <select name="SampleSelect">
    <option>Sample1</option>
    <option>Sample2</option>
    <option>Sample3</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer page:

```
<a href="questions.php">Return to questions</a>

<?php
  $answer = $_POST['SampleSelect'];
  echo $answer;
?>
```

Comment: You certainly can sent a _value_ as a http get argument, so as part of a URL which can be used in an anchor tag (`<a href="script?key=value">value</a>`). But "sending a form" does not make any sense.

Comment: As people mentioned, you can parse your variable through the url, and then retrieve it as a `$_GET`. But out of curiosity, why are you avoiding `AJAX` and/or other `JavaScript` methods? Do you feel like it would over complicate things?

Comment: @Martin yes in some ways. I'm trying to implement this in a wordpress template and I have no idea on implementing it or might complicate some scripts outside of the page

Comment: If you just return to the questions by using the browser's back, the form should be as it was before submission.  What's your aim here - to give feedback/hints/corrections for wrong questions?

Answer (score 3):

### This could be achieved with [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Start or resume a session with [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and then store the answer in the session. The code could look like this:

**answer.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<a href="questions.php">Return to questions</a>

<?php
  $answer = $_POST['SampleSelect'];
  $_SESSION['answer'] = $answer;
  echo $answer;
?>
```

**question.php:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $answer = $_SESSION['answer'];  
  $options = [
    "Sample1",
    "Sample2",
    "Sample3"
  ];
?>

<form action="results.php" method="POST">
  <select name="SampleSelect">
    <?php
      foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option === $answer) {
          echo '<option selected>' . $option . "</option>\n";
        } else {
          echo '<option>' . $answer . "</option>\n";
        }
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: This is hardly what sessions are for.

Comment: A bit overkill to use sessions in this case, but works nonetheless. Great option if OP needs it in multiple files after having posted the variable, or need to keep it out of sight of the user, but that doesn't seem like the case in this question.

Comment: @sskoko can you please explain?

Comment: is it possible to put the returned $_SESSION['answer'] into the dropdown as the value once returned?

Comment: @kalehmann I can use $_SESSION['answer1'] and $_SESSION['answer2'] in the same form/page/session right? or it's much more efficient if I make $_SESSION['answer'] as an array of other variables passed?

Comment: `$_SESSION` already is an array. So you can easily add more values to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass it as a $_GET

```
$var = 'something';
echo "<a href='questions.php?var=$var'>Pass me back</a>";
```

In your questions PHP file you'll grab it:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];
echo $var;
```

Comment: Of course this would make sense only if we have some kind of Data Store (typically some sort of database). For example if you have an ID for your "Results" you  can pass it back to the page that would then request it from the Data Store.

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: you will tell me you would stringify the form data and send it as trough GET? What if there is something sensitive in there OR what if its a long form and the stringified version is over URL GET Length?

Comment: You don't know what is he sending or if it's entire form. He might be just sending simple answer "Yes" or "No" to some question. He asked how to pass it through <a> that's what the answer is about.

Comment: @thefolenangel this is also one of my personal concerns looking at this question, when dealing with `$_GET` methods, which is why I am curious as to why OP is reluctant to use AJAX or similar JavaScript solutions. However, no such "worries" were addressed in the question, and so a `$_GET` method seems like an incredibly simple way of solving OP's problem.